# Dynamic dropdowns won't fill with correct content

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm building a script which grabs some content from a JSON file and dynamically build some html. 
The Html is to display some product information as some sort of lookbook.

Inside the html there are a few dropdown boxes. These boxes are also created dynamically. Everything is working fine except that the content from the last dropdownbox is used for every dropdown that is build. See attached image:
[image]

I personally think that the reason is why this is happening is because the `variants` are build and appended before the actual HTML is build??!

```
$('#sets .set').each( function(){
    ....
    $.getJSON(url, function (data){
        var product = data.product;
        var $container = $('.products .product');
        var productsHtml = [];

        $.each(product.related, function(index, rel){
            $.getJSON(url, function (data){
                var rel = data.product;
                var wqsSelectVariants = $('<div class="product-configure-variants tui" />');
                var select = $('<select id="product_configure_variants"/>');

                $.each(rel.variants, function (index, variant){
                    select.append('<option value=' + variant.id + '>' + variant.title + '</option>');
                    wqsSelectVariants.append(select);
                });

                $('.varianten').html(wqsSelectVariants);
            });

            var productHtml = '' + '<div class="p"><div class="foto"><a href="'+fullurl+''+rel.url+'"><img class="rollover" src="'+image+'" hover="'+image2+'" alt="'+rel.fulltitle+'"/></a></div><div class="prijs" data-price="'+rel.price.price_incl+'">€'+rel.price.price_incl+'</div><div class="varianten"></div></div>';
            productsHtml.push(productHtml);
        });

        productsHtml = productsHtml.join('');
        $container.html(productsHtml);
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="set">
    <div class="right">
        <div class="products">
            <div class="close"></div>
            <div class="product">
                **-- in here the content from the script example below --**
                <div class="p">
                    <div class="foto">
                        <a href="zwart.html">
                            <img alt="Enkellaars zwart" hover="image.jpg" src="image2.jpg" class="rollover">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div data-price="39.95" class="prijs">€39.95</div>
                    <div class="varianten">
                        <div class="product-configure-variants tui">
                            <select id="product_configure_variants">
                                <option value="9996912">Maat: M/L</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- .products -->
    </div><!-- .right -->
    <div class="image">
        <img src="{{ product.image | url_image('220x330x2', product.fulltitle) }}" width="220" height="330" alt="{{ product.fulltitle }}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Does any body know what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: I guess, You are adding it to same container `$('.varianten').html(wqsSelectVariants);` You may need to create containers like .varient-1,.varient-2...

Comment: within `$('#sets .set').each` you need to isolate instance of `$('.varianten')` as it relates to current  instance of `.set`. This is usually a very simple traverse but without any html shown can't help more and is generally simpler than the suggestion made by @Manivannan

Comment: @Manivannan: I tried that with no luck. I added a unique identifier but that didn't do the trick!

Comment: @charlietfl: I've updated my answer with the HTML. What do you mean with isolate instance of varianten?? Do you have an example?

Answer (score 1):

WIthin the loop of `$('#sets .set').each()` the current instance of `.set` is `this`.

So you can isolate the `'.varianten'` for each `.set` by traversing within the current instance only

```
 $('#sets .set').each( function(){
      var $variant =$(this).find('.varianten');

      /* do all the ajax stuff */
});
```

Then change the line:

```
$('.varianten').html(wqsSelectVariants);
```

To

```
$variant.html(wqsSelectVariants);
```

Note that ID's must be unique in a page also.